# error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use an SDK given with the RFID scanner I recently bought.
I'm trying to run the sample code given, but it won't compile. I get the following errors on compilation:

```
error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
error: package RecyclerView does not exist
```

I've tried all the solutions on similar posts, and I'm pretty sure I have the support library correctly installed.

Here are all my dependencies in my build.gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
implementation project(':Rfid.AsciiProtocol-Library')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'

}
```

I'm new to Android Studio, and as I said I tried pretty much all the answers for similar problems and nothing works, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace android support recyclerview with androidx

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

And you can delete 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' dependency, because you've already import it with

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, it unfortunately still gives the same error...

Comment: Did you click on gradle sync? What error do you get now?

Comment: Maybe it is left in some of your classes import from support lib. So check your imports in your project, wherever you have RecyclerView, you need to delete previous import from support lib, and import it from androidx package. Same with android.support.v7.widget, search it in whole project and delete it.

Comment: @BanMarkovich , How do I delete previous import from support lib? So for example in one of the activity I have "import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;"  at the very begining. Do you mean to delete that? 
Sorry, I'm really new to android Studio. And thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes you are correct, delete that line "import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;", and than if Android Studio show error for RecyclerView, it will give you option to import it from new lib.

Answer (score 1):

It frustrated me for literally hours because the answer here given is missing so much.

In dependencies of gradle:
import:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

click gradle sync (should be a bar on top of the page that pops up

Then in your java file where u actually use the RecyclerView class, import this:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

and you are done

EDIT: So apprently you just need to auto-fill the object you need and android studio will auto inport for you. example:
try to type recyclerview, but press tab to auto-fill it. The object should automatically be imported for you on top of the java page. This works with all android studio objects like view and intent.